# Run time error 91, object variable or with block variable not set

Tags: vba, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest, web-crawler

My intention is to scrape all the app name from that page and the app link leading to the next page. However, when i run it, i see that after looping once it produces the following error "Run time error 91, object variable or with block variable not set".Here is the full code. Any help would really be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
Sub app_crawler()
    Dim xmlpage As New XMLHTTP60, htmldoc As New HTMLDocument
    Dim htmlas As Object, htmla As Object, sstr As String

    xmlpage.Open "GET", "https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/candy-crush-saga/id553834731?mt=8", False
    xmlpage.send
    htmldoc.body.innerHTML = xmlpage.responseText

    For Each htmlas In htmldoc.getElementsByClassName("lockup-info")(0).getElementsByTagName("a")
        sstr = htmlas.href

        xmlpage.Open "GET", sstr, False
        xmlpage.send
        htmldoc.body.innerHTML = xmlpage.responseText

        For Each htmla In htmldoc.getElementsByClassName("intro")(1).getElementsByTagName("h1")
            x = x + 1: Cells(x, 1) = htmla.innerText
        Next htmla
    Next htmlas
End Sub
```

Comment: On which line do you get the error?

Comment: *I just copied the complete code and pasted here to avoid confusion what I'm asking* - unfortunately you've basically given us a procedure and said "it's not working", without giving us any indication about exactly where the problem might be, or showing any form of effort on your part to try and isolate the issue to a single specific instruction. Can you try to do that and [edit] your question?

Comment: You need to **[edit]** that information *into your question*.

Comment: Also, your question has probably been answered hundreds of times over already (just look at all the "related" questions in the side bar). You *do* know that you can't do `Foo.Bar("abc")` if `Foo` is `Nothing`, right? Separate your chained calls, and handle situations where `htmlas(x)` returns `Nothing`, then handle situations where `getElementsByTagName("a")` returns `Nothing`.

Comment: Dreadfully sorry for that mistake. This is my first ever question here so i don't know the manner of asking. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @ShahinIqbal http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer which fixes all the problems I was having:

```
Sub app_crawler()
    Dim http As New XMLHTTP60, hdoc As New HTMLDocument, hdoc_one As New HTMLDocument
    Dim elem As Object, post As Object, sstr As String

    With http
        .Open "GET", "https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/candy-crush-saga/id553834731?mt=8", False
        .send
        hdoc.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    For Each elem In hdoc.getElementsByClassName("lockup-info")
        With elem.getElementsByTagName("li")(0).getElementsByTagName("a")
            If .Length Then sstr = .Item(0).href
        End With
        With http
            .Open "GET", sstr, False
            .send
            hdoc_one.body.innerHTML = .responseText
        End With

        For Each post In hdoc_one.getElementsByClassName("intro")
            With post.getElementsByTagName("h1")
                If .Length Then i = i + 1: Cells(i, 1) = .Item(0).innerText
            End With
        Next post
    Next elem
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

As [Mat's Mug](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1188513/mats-mug) [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41488860/run-time-error-91-object-variable-or-with-block-variable-not-set#comment70183972_41488860), you'll have to test if `htmlas(x)` returns `Nothing` before getting elements from it, and the same applies for `getElementByTagName` and others:

```
Sub TestSth()
  Dim xmlpage As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
  Dim htmldoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
  Dim htmlas As Object, gist As Object
  Dim htmla As Object, main As Object, lux As String
  Dim x As Long, link As Object, thank As Object
  Range("A1").Select
  xmlpage.Open "GET", "https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/candy-crush-saga/id553834731?mt=8", False
  xmlpage.send
  htmldoc.body.innerHTML = xmlpage.responseText
  Set xmlpage = Nothing

  Set htmlas = htmldoc.getElementsByClassName("lockup-info")
  For x = 0 To htmlas.Length - IIf(htmlas.Length > 0, 1, 0)
    If Not htmlas(x) Is Nothing Then
      If Not htmlas(x).getElementsByTagName("a") Is Nothing Then
        If Not htmlas(x).getElementsByTagName("a")(0) Is Nothing Then
          lux = htmlas(x).getElementsByTagName("a")(0).getAttribute("href")
          If lux <> "" Then
            xmlpage.Open "GET", lux, False
            xmlpage.send
            htmldoc.body.innerHTML = xmlpage.responseText

            Set main = htmldoc.getElementsByClassName("intro")(1)
            Set thank = main.getElementsByTagName("div")
            For Each link In thank
              ActiveCell.Value = link.innertext
              ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            Next link
          End If
        End If
      End If
    End If
  Next x
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort but it doesn't pull the whole data it should. I have already solved the problem last night. Here is what's i was expecting: